# input:checked não está aplicando as propriedades

Tags: css, css3

Estou desenvolvendo um menu responsivo usando css3 (não posso usar JS), e estou com um problema que está me impedindo de avançar, o problema é o seguinte :

```
input:checked ~ nav {
  display: none;
}
```

Porém a propriedade não é aplicada ao nav quando o input é marcado.

Exemplo do código problema em um código :

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input:checked ~ nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTATOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FALE CONOSCO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
</body>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é que o seletor `~` se refere a um elemento que é precedido por outro dentro do mesmo "pai" da estrutura em árvore do arquivo, e não é o caso do seu HTML.

Da [documentação do W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators):

> **8.3.2. General sibling combinator**
>
> *The general sibling combinator is made of the "tilde" (U+007E, ~) character that separates two sequences of simple selectors. The elements represented by the two sequences **share the same parent** in the document tree and the element represented by the first sequence precedes (not necessarily immediately) the element represented by the second one.*

<sup>(grifo meu, na parte que nos interessa)</sup>

Que em resumo é isto:

> O combinador de "irmão genérico" é o "til" (`~`), que separa duas sequências de seletores simples. Os elementos tem um **pai em comum** na árvore do documento, e o primeiro dos elementos precede o segundo, não necessariamente imediatamente.

No seu caso, o "pai" dos elementos é diferente, só o "avô" é o mesmo.

Tem muitas maneiras de se resolver, a melhor só depende do geral do seu código. O importante é entender como funcionam os seletores do CSS.

### Exemplos de solução:

Uma solução seria por o `nav` dentro da `div`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input:checked ~ nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <input type="checkbox" />
      <nav>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">CONTATOS</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">FALE CONOSCO</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Outra seria tirar o `input` da `div`:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

input:checked ~ nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <input type="checkbox" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTATOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FALE CONOSCO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
</body>
```

### Mas se precisar mesmo de um elemento dentro da div:

Você pode usar um `label` como "controle remoto" do checkbox:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

#toggle,
input:checked ~ nav {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="menu">
      <label for="toggle">[clique aqui]</label>
    </div>
    <input id="toggle" type="checkbox" />
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">INICIO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SOBRE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CONTATOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FALE CONOSCO</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PROJETOS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  
</body>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! Uma bela explicação hahaha.